# dropdown-toggle in clickable tr

Tags: jquery, toggle, dropdown, clickable, tr

```
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='details.html'>
    ...
    <td>
     <div class="ibox-tools">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle doDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <script>
      $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
         window.location = $(this).data("href");
      });

      $('.doDropdown').click(function( event ) {
         $(this).dropdown();
         return false;
     </script>
```

i created clickable tr-elements in a table which lead to a new page. in every tr is a td at the end, with a dropdown-toggle, which should not trigger the tr-event but instead only open the dropdown.

i tried to prevent the href-event by using event.stopPropagation() but this also kills the toggle event. so i used $(this).dropdown("toggle") to fire the toggle event again but i got the feeling this will get too complicated for just that simple behaviour.

is there an easy way out?

Comment: $(this).dropdown(); return false;

with does 2 lines of code i can prevent the href and the dropdown ALMOST works properly, which means the first click on the toggle doesn't do anything, after the second click it works normally... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` actually works.

html:

```
<table>
  <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='details.html'>
    <td>
      some content here
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ibox-tools">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle doDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-wrench">Action</i>          
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

script:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
         //window.location = $(this).data("href");
         alert('row click');
      });

$('.doDropdown').click(function( event ) {
    alert('dropdown click');
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  //$(this).dropdown();
 });
```

You still need to update to whatever you want to do with your dropdown. In my case I'm toggling visibility of it.

Also, since your dropdown itself is in table - you need to terminate even propagation on each element as well.. or pull `dropdown-menu` outside of table.

One more trick is to subscribe event to `td` and leave `td` with dropdown unsubscribed.

```
$('.clickable-row td:not(:last)').click(...);
```

Comment: thank you! this is a good solution, but every row has a list-element class="dropdown-menu", so now every dropdown opens when I click one :) i tried $(this).closest but wasn't able to get it running

Comment: $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggle(); will to the trick. or `$(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').toggle();` which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: good to know thanks! the only thing left is: before i started adding all that javascript i could click anywhere on the page and the dropdown closed. now i have to click on the toggle to close it. any good ideas left? :)

Comment: that's because in the example I gave we are closing/opening dropdown in our code, before you was using `.dropdown()` plugin (i thing bootstrap or foundation). You can switch back you the plugin you used before - events now should work for you correctly.

Comment: perfect! i trigger the bootstrap event with $(this).trigger('click.bs.dropdown');